Got error when trying to write to a TextField in XCTest
In my code below, the TextField is seen by the framework as a .textView elementType. When I write to it, I get the following error
Failed to synthesize event: Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus. Event dispatch snapshot: **TextView**, {{0.0, 430.0}, {414.0, 46.0}}, identifier: 'MyTextView', placeholderValue: 'stackOverflow', value: stackOverflow

How do I fix the above error? That is, is it possible to tap and write to a multi-line TextField? Or, I need to replace it with TextEditor?
Below is the app code for iOS
struct TestTextView: View {
        @State private var text = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TextField("<input>", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                    .lineLimit(2, reservesSpace: true)
                    .border(Color.black)
                    .accessibilityIdentifier("MyTextView")
            }
        }
} // TestTextView()

Below is XCTest code
func testTextView() throws {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
        
        let accessId = "MyTextView"
        let field = app.textViews[accessId]
        XCTAssertTrue(field.exists, "TextField '\(accessId)' does not exist|debug = \(app.debugDescription)")

        field.tap()
        field.typeText("Hello")
}

When I configure the TextField as a one-line view (by removing axis and lineLimit), the framework sees it as .textField, and I'm able to write to it.
